# DiceGame returns an error saying there is no variable when I have declared one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, syntax, python-3.5

I'm an amateur 15 year old programmer who's relatively new to functions in Python and have never done OOP Python, however I've delved into it slightly. Our class project is to make a simple dice game however I've tried to expand on my skills. The source code will be below and I will leave comments where I would like help (so don't tell me there's a hash, that's there to let you know where I think I've gone wrong). Whenever I run the program, the console comes up with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 5, in <module>
  File "python", line 52, in DiceGame
  File "python", line 30, in main
NameError: name 'sides' is not defined
```

Here is the source code:

```
#Jabir Hussains Source Code - Dice Task
import random

x = "Error!"

class DiceGame():
  def sides():
    sides = int(input("How many sides would you like on your di[c]e?"))
    if sides > 10:
      print("Sorry, the developer didn't have the time to program above 10 dice")
      sides = int(input("How many sides do you like on your di[c]e?"))
    elif sides < 6:
      print("The limit is 6 sides. Please try again")
      sides = int(input("How many sides do you like on your di[c]e?")) #Here I've defined the number of sides
    else:
      return sides
  sides()

  def diceNum():
    numDice = int(input("How many dice would you like?"))
    if numDice > 2:
      print("We're limited to 2 dice, please try again")
    elif numDice < 1:
      print("That is mathematically impossible. Please try again")
      numDice = int(input("How many dice would you like?"))
    else:
      return numDice
  diceNum()

  def main():
    if sides == 6 and numDice == 1:
      print("The number is",random.randint(1,6),"!")
    elif sides == 6 and numDice == 2:
      print("The numbers are",random.randint(1,6),"and",random.randint(1,6),"!")
    elif sides == 7 and numDice == 1:
      print("The number is",random.randint(1,7),"!")
    elif sides == 7 and numDice == 2:
      print("The numbers are",random.randint(1,7),"and",random.randint(1,7),"!")
    elif sides == 8 and numDice == 1:
      print("The number is",random.randint(1,8),"!")
    elif sides == 8 and numDice == 2:
      print("The numbers are",random.randint(1,8),"and",random.randint(1,8),"!")
    elif sides == 9 and numDice == 1:
      print("The number is",random.randint(1,9),"!")
    elif sides == 9 and numDice == 2:
      print("The numbers are",random.randint(1,9),"and",random.randint(1,9),"!")
    elif sides == 10 and numDice == 1:
      print("The number is",random.randint(1,10),"!")
    elif sides == 10 and numDice == 2:
      print("The numbers are",random.randint(1,10),"and",random.randint(1,10),"!")
    else:
      print(x)
  main()
DiceGame()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is so much wrong here I'm not sure where to start.

But the main points would be:

1) You should define a class from "object"

```
class YourClass(object):
```

2) You need an **init** method (it is sort of like a constructor, look this up)

```
def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
```

3) In order to use an object from a class you have to instantiate it

```
yourObject = YourClass(arg1, arg2)
```

After you do that you can do:

```
yourObject.yourFunction()
```

I hope this helps, but check the documentation:

https://docs.python.org/2.7/

Comment: I've never looked into OOP before so thats probably one reason why.